# Ctrl+Shift+Left bracket ([) Sends object back one position vs. all the way to back as expected on Powerpoint 365

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, microsoft-powerpoint, office365

I've recently been moved over to Office 365 and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd> used to be the shortcut to move an object all the way to the back. Now it seems it just moves it back one position (which used to be <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd>. Seems that's how it should still be according to [MS website](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/use-keyboard-shortcuts-to-create-powerpoint-presentations-ebb3d20e-dcd4-444f-a38e-bb5c5ed180f4?ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us#PickTab=Windows).

Is there a new shortcut I should use instead?

Comment: I repro this here @Bobby D.  To report it, choose File | Feedback, click "I don't like" and describe the problem. The devs will see it this way. I've already done the same.

Answer (score 0):

Here are two ways that I send objects to the front and back.

## Two-Key Method

### Add "Send to Back" and "Bring to Front" to the Quick Access Toolbar

[This is what the default Quick Access Toolbar looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MqjUE.png)

Here's how to add to it:

1. Select an object on your slide
2. Home (tab) > Arrange > ***Right-Click*** Bring to Front > Select "Add to Quick Access Toolbar"
   [[Screenshot]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8dE0r.png)
3. This adds it to your Quick Access Toolbar [[Screenshot]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n2tTF.png)
4. With an object still selected, press the **ALT** key on your keyboard.
5. This will show you the assigned numbers for your Quick Access Toolbar buttons. Mine is number 7 [[Screenshot]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Snfvp.png)
6. Repeat Step 2 but this time add "Send to Back" to your Quick Access Toolbar
7. Simply press ALT+7 to bring objects to the front or ALT+8 to send objects to the back (your numbers may differ depending on how many items you have in your Quick Access Toolbar)

---

## Four-Key Method

### Tap keys in succession (you don't have to hold down any keys)

**Bring to Front:** ALT, H, G, R

**Send to Back:** ALT, H, G, K